# How to make a new Dart file using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I Make quickly new dart file for my new project in Android Studio?

I am trying with CTRL+N and also tries some other Shortcuts but they didn't work..

So please tell me the Keyboard Shortcut key for Creating new Dart file instantly...

Comment: Which IDE?  Makes a difference. :)

Comment: Android Studio..

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comments for Android Studio

#### First way combining shortcuts:

If you just want to use your keyboard this is how you do it:

- Take the focus to project file explorer using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>             (for MAC: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>)
- Go to your desired path with arrow keys
- Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> (for MAC: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) the new file window opens select Dart File with arrow keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Second way Create New Shortcut

Go to `Files > Settings > Keymap` and search for "Dart File", right click on in it and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut` and in the input select a key combination  (I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>) and press OK and Apply.